# Dynamic number of columns Ionic 2

Tags: responsive-design, ionic2

I am building a mobile app using Ionic 2 and one of the requirements I have is to display 4 cards in one row if displayed in tablet and only 2 cards in a row if displayed in a mobile. I was wondering what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you share some of your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could essentially just give them a width with a min-width and let them reposition themselves. Something like

```
.card {
    width: calc(100%/4);
    min-width: calc(356px/2); // most minimum width of your container on a phone.
}
```

Probably your best bet though would be to go the responsive route. Just use a @media screen and (max-width="768px") or whatever you need to set it at and change the values there.

```
.card {
    width: calc(100%/4);
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .card {
         width: calc(100%/2);        
    }
}
```

and you could do this with an *ngStyle if you wished to apply it via angular. Just create a string to match the value with and run an *ngIf statement to apply the separate values.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but you probably want to use ionic platform somewhere you could try something like on the `<ion-col>` element you can add `[attr.width-50]` for the iphone and `[attr.width-25]` for the ipad.

```
<ion-col [attr.width-50]="isIphoneOrIpad" [attr.width-25]="!isIphoneOrIpad">
```

You can then write the logic for the return boolean in the corresponding `.ts` file using Platform.

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export MyPage {
  isIphoneOrIpad:boolean;  

  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
    this.isIphoneOrIpad = this.platform.is('iphone') || this.platform.is('ipad');
  }  
}
```

Which will return true or false and then display the attribute accordingly.

For more information check out the [Ionic 2 Platform Documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/)